# Facebook graph api, likes list

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Graph API, "GET me/likes" returns result only for pages.

I want to get the list for friend's post that I like.

```
https://www.facebook.com/{user-id}/allactivity
https://www.facebook.com/{user-id}/allactivity?privacy_source=activity_log&log_filter=likes
```

Is it available to get this data with Graph API?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/